# move already uploaded file to new location in laravel4

Tags: php, file, laravel-4, file-move

how to move a already uploaded file to another location in laravel4. i'm saving the uploaded files in a temporary folder in my project folder with path `'public/images/temp/'`. **files are uploading to that temp folder successfully**. but i'm doing a payment option in between this. so only if the payment is succesfull i need to move that flies from temp folder to another folder by renaming it, path is `'public/images/consult/'` .

i tried FILE::Move() and FILE::delete() but didn't work. the code i used is:

```
$filename1 = Session::get('email_filename1'); //filename of file stored in temporary folder

$ext = substr(strrchr($filename1,'.'),1);

$newfilename1 = 'Email_'.Str::random(20).'_'.Session::get('patient_id').'.'.$ext;

$oldfile = public_path().'images/consultation_files/temp/'.$filename1;

$newfile = public_path().'images/consultation_files/'.$newfilename1;

 File::move($oldfile, $newfile);
```

if anyone knows please share your solutions. it will be so helpful..

The log shows:

[2015-02-05 11:27:54] log.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /var/www/html/myrpoject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1429
Stack trace:#0 /var/www/html/myrpoject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1050): Illuminate\Routing\Router->handleRoutingException(Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException))

:#1/var/www/html/myrpoject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1014): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

:#2/var/www/html/myrpoject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(530): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

:#3/var/www/html/myrpoject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(506): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

:#4 /var/www/html/myrpoject/public/index.php(50): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()

:#5 {main} [] []

Comment: Deleting the file shouldn't be necessary since you moved it. Also what does "didn't work" mean? Do you get an error or is the file just not moved? Check `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Does the log file contain any information?

Comment: @lukasgeiter :Hi..  i have added the log msg in my post now..

Comment: That error means your code is never executed because the route is not found. Can you add the relevant route and controller action?

Comment: the code that i had displayed in the post is the code in the Homecontroller method with one extra line as to redirect to a view when success. and in router.php i just added `Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');`

Comment: I need a bit more to be able to tell what the problem is. Maybe the redirect is failing. Remove it and see if you still have an error.

Comment: @lukasgeiter : hi.. i got the error now like this when i use FILE::move() as a shown in the post. `rename(/var/www/html/myproject/public/images/consultation_files/temp/tmp_email_ktII0QpHz6jFMZThsWTw_177.jpg,/var/www/html/myproject/public/images/consultation_files/tmp_email_ktII0QpHz6jFMZThsWTw_177.jpg): No such file or directory `

Comment: but the files are present in that folder with 777 permission

Comment: hey.. at last it worked !! :) i use rename()

Comment: So `rename()` directly worked but `File::move()` didn't? That's pretty hard to believe because `File::move()` does nothing but call `rename()` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Use `File::copy()` method

`$source` will be your Source and `$destination` will be your desitination

```
if ( ! File::copy($source, $desitination))
{
    die("Couldn't copy file");
}
```

To delete a file use `File::delete($filename);` and for multiple file use `File::delete($file1, $file2, $file3);`

And if it fails, see the `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` as lukasgeiter suggests

I would suggest to check for `File::exists()` and then perform the `File::delete($filename);`

[More Information here](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html)

Comment: hi.. i checked it with file copy but nothing happended.. instead the page broken and a white screen appears :(